# Is there a way to access a database and also a dataframe at the same time using SQL in Python?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, database, dataframe

Is there a way to access a database and also a dataframe using SQL in Python?

For example, is it possible to do something like ...

```
select a.*, b.* from {database} as a left join {dataframe} as b on a.key = b.key
```

where *database* is data on an SQL server and *dataframe* is a Python (Pandas or otherwise) dataframe ... ?

Answer (score 0):

yes, it's possible to access a database and also a dataframe using SQL in Python.

You can use [pandasql](https://pypi.org/project/pandasql/) library to run SQL queries on the dataframe.

You may try something like this

```
import pandas as pd
from pandasql import sqldf

# Read the data from a SQL database into a dataframe
conn = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM your_table', your_database_connection)

# Create a Python dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'key': [1, 2, 3], 'value': ['a', 'b', 'c']})

# Merge the two dataframes using SQL
query = '''
    SELECT a.*, b.*
    FROM conn AS a
    LEFT JOIN df AS b
    ON a.key = b.key
'''
result = sqldf(query, locals())

# Display the result
print(result)
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified - it has to be at the same time. The database is too big to load into memory...

Comment: you may then think of trying Spark SQL (pyspark.sql module in Python)

Comment: @lithic then you should probably just make a table out of the dataframe then let the database handle the query

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to express the {dataframe} as a constant SELECT on a fake-table

In Oracle/MySQL:

```
SELECT 'Hello world' as column1
FROM DUAL
```

In Postgres:

```
SELECT 'Hello world' as column1
```

You achieve this in SQLAlchemy by using `literals`.

This approach depends on the size of your {dataframe} and could lead to a huge SQL command.